# Get exact filter results with charset utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-like, cultureinfo, utf8mb4

I want to match filter results exactly using CHARACTER SET utf8mb4.

```
ALTER DATABASE test CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE users (    
username VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,    
password VARCHAR(25) NULL NULL
) 
ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
CREATE  INDEX  users_username_idx ON users (username);
```

I inserted 1 million rows also containing below rows.

```
INSERT INTO users SELECT 'üsasdasd','somepassword';
INSERT INTO users SELECT 'usasdasd','somepassword';
INSERT INTO users SELECT 'pğasdasdasd','somepassword';
INSERT INTO users SELECT 'anfüs','somepassword';
INSERT INTO users SELECT 'anfus','somepassword';
```

Then applied some queries.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'üs%';
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'us%';
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'pğ%';
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'anfüs';
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'anfus';
```

Why do i get results that ALSO have ü letter(like üsasdasd or anfüs) when i filter as `"LIKE 'us%'"` or `" = 'anfus'"`
OR
Why do i get results that ALSO have u letter(like usasdasd or anfus) when i filter as `"LIKE 'üs%'"` or `" = 'anfüs'"` ?

How can i get results that ONLY have ü letter(like üsasdasd or anfüs) when i filter as `"LIKE 'üs%'"` or `" = 'anfüs'"` vice versa ?

```
ANSWER:
```

I dont know why but, COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_as_cs fixed the issue.

Comment: Any reason that you are not using COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ?

Comment: unfortunately it did not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passwords, you want to ignore *all* case folding, accent stripping, etc, so use `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`.

I suspect `utf8mb4_0900_as_cs` is not quite the same as `_bin`.

On the other hand, do you really want to store "plaintext" passwords?  A common technique is to store a hash of the pwd and do the hash when testing.  A simple hash that is secure from casual hackers:

```
MD5(CONCAT(password, 'my secret salt'))
```

Comment: yes utf8mb4_bin also worked for me. But what is the  actual difference? is it case folding?

Comment: All `_bin` collations compare bit-for-bit.  No case folding, no nothing.  I have not researched the new-with-8.0 `..._as_cs` collations; the name implies "Accent Sensitive and Case Sensitive", but there are other things that Collations check.